# "ntpd unable to bind to wildcard address 0.0.0.0 - another process may be running"

Tags: ntp

On my Ubuntu 13.04 (using AWS). When I start a new machine or when I reboot my machine `ntp` does not start and I see the following in the syslog:

```
Jan 10 02:56:49 ntpd: unable to bind to wildcard address 0.0.0.0 - another process may be running - EXITING
```

I also notice that before this ntpdate was used to adjust time

```
Jan 10 02:45:20 ntpdate[960]: adjust time server offset -0.000259 sec
```

I am not sure if this is a race condition or me missing something here, I would appreciate if anyone can help me out here.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the ntpdate is running when you try to start the server. I haven't found reasons why to leave it installed so you could remove it if you are using ntp daemon:

```
sudo apt-get remove ntpdate
```

Answer (score 7):

I've seen this on Debian Jessie. The cause appears to be a race between `/etc/init.d/ntp` and `/etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate`, both of which appear to contain logic to lock each other out that doesn't actually work.

I like having the ntpdate command available even though I rarely use it, so rather than uninstall ntpdate altogether I've just inserted

```
exit 0
```

as the second line of `/etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate`, which makes it do nothing. My ntp daemon now starts successfully at boot time.

Comment: This worked for me and this is a persistent change, but it might confuse the upgrade-wizard/process,  when the system is upgraded to the next release.

Comment: The "logic... that doesn't actually work" may be because it depends on having package lockfile-progs installed. Without that, the relevant blocks are silently skipped and the locking will not work.

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar problem on Debian 5,

a simple restart of ntp solved it for me

```
/etc/init.d/ntp stop
/etc/init.d/ntp start
```

just in case other have same problem

NTPD was recently installed, it seems that a restart after install is needed, I noticed this on Debian 6 also.

Comment: This worked for me and solved the immediate issue.

Answer (score 3):

This was [fixed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=436029) in 2008 by adding locking, but if you disabled installing `Recommends` or uninstalled `lockfile-progs` then you will still have this problem (note that you should expect problems if you disabled installing `Recommends`).

Comment: AFAICT, in Jessie (8.8) it doesn't Recommend lockfile-progs :(.  In Stretch (9.0), it is fixed again by calling the `flock` command instead.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @sourcejedi https://packages.debian.org/jessie/ntpdate

Comment: Heh, I had an assumption they would put the Recommends on both packages.  Thanks again :).

Comment: @sourcejedi ntpd doesn't need to lock against itself

Comment: I have 16.04 and still see this problem after a `logrotate`. `lockfile-progs` is installed and it does not happen every time. Is `ntpdate` run once in a while and blocking `ntpd` at such times?