# ntpd not adjusting the time

Tags: ntp

In my Ubuntu 14.10 `ntp` doesn't seem to work. If I call:

```
ntpd -g -q
```

This is the output in syslog:

```
Dec 12 20:33:26 nebelhaufen ntpd[28659]: ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Wed Oct  9 18:56:59 UTC 2013 (1)
Dec 12 20:33:26 nebelhaufen ntpd[28659]: proto: precision = 0.200 usec
Dec 12 20:33:26 nebelhaufen ntpd[28659]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket boundary: 16
Dec 12 20:33:26 nebelhaufen ntpd[28659]: unable to bind to wildcard address 0.0.0.0 - another process may be running - EXITING
root@nebelhaufen:/var/www/bz/www/blimusdev# Dec 12 20:33:26 nebelhaufen kernel: [22320.780176] audit: type=1400 audit(1418412806.510:66): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/usr/local/sbin/" pid=28659 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Dec 12 20:33:26 nebelhaufen kernel: [22320.780185] audit: type=1400 audit(1418412806.510:67): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/usr/local/bin/" pid=28659 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

How can I set the time on Ubuntu via ntpd?

---

EDIT: `ntpdate -q ntp.ubuntu.com` works fine, but I read, that `ntpdate` is deprecated?

Comment: Did you try to stop ntp service (`sudo service ntp stop`) before running `ntpd -g -q`, then start it afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to run a network daemon, and this line is the main problem:

```
unable to bind to wildcard address 0.0.0.0 - another process may be running - EXITING
```

First suspect is if you are root or not; low ports are not for non-root users.
The second is it seems also `ntpdate` is running as damon after install: ["ntpd unable to bind to wildcard address 0.0.0.0 - another process may be running"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403616/ntpd-unable-to-bind-to-wildcard-address-0-0-0-0-another-process-may-be-runnin?rq=1)

If your system is already running ntpd, `ps ax|grep ntp` shows that?
If so, stop it with

```
sudo service ntp stop
```

before running

```
ntpd -g -q
```

Comment: still not working. I uninstalled ntpdate and tried `service ntp restart` which causes another "ntpd: unable to bind to wildcard address 0.0.0.0 - another process may be running - EXITING" in syslog

Answer (score 0):

Run `netstat -pnl | grep 123` to identify the process that is listening on port 123, kill it, then restart ntp.