# Disabling ntp.service for the boot, since it takes a long time

Tags: boot

For some time now my computer has been very slow to boot. So yesterday I did a `systemd-analyze blame`, which from what I understand gives you the processes that take the longest to start. So these are the first lines of mine

```
3min 45.244s ntp.service
     45.277s apt-daily.service
     12.114s dev-sda1.device
      9.200s ModemManager.service
      7.698s NetworkManager.service
```

So apparently `ntp.service` is by far taking the longest. I have done some research but I couldn't precisely figure out what it's important for and how I can disable it.

Is it safe for me to disable it? How can I disable it for boot?

Comment: Brother if you don't know what it is or does don't mess with it, better it takes 3mins than your system taking forever or not boot at all! Its called the _network time service_ used to synchronize time on your system.

Comment: I have a backup of my system. Worst case scenario I'll re-install Linux, so I think it's worth the risk. I manually disabled it  and nothing really changed, so I'm guessing it's not extremely important.

Comment: Does `sudo systemctl status ntp[d]` return anything?

Comment: @George Yes, a bunch of lines. The most important is probably the one that says `unable to bind to wildcard address :: - another process may be running - EXITING`. But this might because I manually disabled it a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: @George I just re-started ntp and ran status again and the message persists. I have no idea what it means

Comment: Restart the system it should correct itself.

Comment: First read https://askubuntu.com/questions/403616/ from three years before this.  The important part of the question here is not actually in it, but is buried in a question comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network Time Protocol:

> NTP- is a protocol which runs over port 123 UDP at Transport Layer and allows computers to synchronize time over networks for an accurate time. While time is passing by, computers internal clocks tend to drift which can lead to inconsistent time issues, especially on servers and clients logs files or if you want to replicate servers resources or databases.

Commands:

1. Stop:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop ntp
   ```
2. Start:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start ntp
   ```
3. Disable at start-up:

   ```
   sudo systemctl disable ntp
   ```
4. Enable at start-up:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable ntp
   ```

Source:

http://www.tecmint.com/install-ntp-server-in-centos/

Comment: Ok but is it safe for me to disable it?

Comment: I would advice leaving it as is..time means a lot to our systems!